# WinHTTP VBA subsequent request cannot use the previous login credentials?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, typo3, winhttp, winhttprequest

I'm using WinHTTP in Access 2007 VBA to fetch some list of items requiring a **cookie login credential account**.

First I login through https://www.example.com/login.php with this:

```
  Dim strCookie As String, strResponse As String, _
    strUrl As String
'
  Dim xobj As Object
'
  Set xobj = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
'
  strUrl = "https://www.example.com/login.php"
  xobj.Open "POST", strUrl, False
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xobj.Send "username=johndoe2&password=mypassword"
'
  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText
```

The content of *strResponse* indicates that my login is OK, as **johndoe2** is welcomed in this string. *strCookie* saves the Set-Cookie returned by the HTTP server after the successful login.

Next I need to get a confidential page only accessible for a logged user: https://www.example.com/secret-contents.php. I do this, with previous Set-Cookie header *strCookie*, resent to the server:

```
'
' now try to get confidential contents:
'
  strUrl = "https://www.example.com/secret-contents.php"
  xobj.Open "GET", strUrl, False
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie
  xobj.Send
'
  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText
```

Unfortunately, it's failed, as the new *strResponse* indicates that the fetched content is not the required one, but rather again the login page. And also *strCookie* has changed.

This has been tested and produces no effect, as it's only for Windows/OS linked authentication, such as the famous basic, NTLM, digest and Kerberos authentications, not for that based on cookie:

```
xobj.SetCredentials "johndoe2", "mypassword", 0
```

What else to send as headers to the remote server other than Set-Cookie, in order to use the previously certified credential ?

The server uses typo3 CMS framework.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to look at what headers are used when running this process in a browser then compare with what your generated requests look like

Comment: Have you the fiddler URL for this kind of code, please ?

Comment: Voila: http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Thank you @Alex K. I installed fiddler 2 and See in Cookie/Login section things that strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie") did not get.

Comment: And more these addition cookie vars are random setting strings...

Comment: @Alex K., I've put what I found today as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this half day, I finally figured out how to use the previous login credential for subsequent requests, thanks to the help of [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k), [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) has opened the door to enter the HTTP headers's world. I would like to share what has worked for me today.

The work consists of 2 steps, login via a URL1 and then fetch the HTML content of the credential required URL2.

#### 1. Login via URL1, kept the same as in the Question:

```
  Dim strCookie As String, strResponse As String, _
    strUrl As String
'
  Dim xobj As Object
'
  Set xobj = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
'
  strUrl = "https://www.example.com/login.php"
  xobj.Open "POST", strUrl, False
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xobj.Send "username=johndoe2&password=mypassword"
'
  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText
```

#### 2. Get the content of the username/password protected URL2:

```
'
' now try to get confidential contents:
'
  strUrl = "https://www.example.com/secret-contents.php"
  xobj.Open "GET", strUrl, False
'
' these 2 instructions are determining:
'
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
'
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie
  xobj.Send
'
  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText
```

One notices the usage of two additional headers sent to the HTTTP server in the second step:

**"Connection", "keep-alive"**

**"User-Agent", "My pretending navigator blabla..."**

without them the URL2 could not be successfully fetched, instead, a good configured website will redirect you to URL1 for authentication again.

In one word, the session must have a **keep-alive** Connection in order to re-use the gained login credential.

This works indifferently for the **http** and **https** protocols.

The HTML login input field names depend on the target site, here **username** and **password**.
The conceiver of the website may use such words as **user**, **pass**; **loginuser**, **loginpass**; ... you can easily figure this out by looking at the source code of the login form.

Comment: hi, can you please help with my question, it has a bounty on it. i have the same problem but this code doesn't work((( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332598/vba-downloading-file-with-login-isnt-working