# Vba download file from internet WinHttpReq with login not working

Tags: vba, csv, authentication, download, winhttp

I have been looking for a solution to automatize the dowload of a csv table from a site, but I haven't found a working solution.

If I get on IE or Chrome, after previous log in I enter the url and the file automatically start dowloading. At this purpose I have another way of achieving what I need through IE and HTML object by navigating and then saving, but it uses sendkeys and it is not a suitable solution. 
I also tried to achieve that by a WinHttpReq download which to me seems the most efficient and elegant way to do it. The problem is : **it downloads the file but unfortunately it outputs a `csv` file with the HTML code of the login page** -> Thus it must fail logging in. The site is an HTTP.

Following my code which I found posted as is in several forums.

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
valore = Range("f6").value
myURL = "www.myurlpointingtodownload.com"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "eimail@g.com", "passs"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\mee\Desktop\fileoioi.csv", 2 
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you, 
bob.

Comment: Passing a username and password like that works for the basic HTTP authentication scheme; if the site uses a different form based login system you will need to login programmatically by submitting the login form, capture returned cookies and include them in your request for the csv file.

Comment: Thanks Alex!I found this anwer of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294956/winhttp-vba-subsequent-request-cannot-use-the-previous-login-credentials), but when I try executing it says "The request header was not found" (How should I det the cookie?)

Comment: Sorry but I really am not expert on cokies and headers : Actually I've tried using Fiddler and I can see the client, the Cookies/login etc... but then I don't really know which one I should copy and where. (when I check the cokies section I see there are utma, utmv, utmz...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to alex and Kyle's hints I looked up to these 2 posts which solved my problem.

nb -> no cookie handling and Fiddlr body copy of the http POST request the 2 required steps for me

here it is my solution:

```
Sub eds()

Dim strCookie As String, strResponse As String, _
  strUrl As String
  Dim xobj As Object
  Dim WinHttpReq As Object
  Set xobj = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

  UN = "2myusername"
  PW = "mypass"

  strUrl = "http://my.website.com/"
  xobj.Open "POST", strUrl, False 
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xobj.Send "username=" & UN & "&password=" & PW & "&login=login" 
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText

  strUrl = http://my.website.com/date=09-10-1945%&search 'the url pointing to the CSV file
  xobj.Open "GET", strUrl, False

  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
  xobj.Send

  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseBody

 If xobj.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write xobj.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\me\Desktop\ciao\file.csv", 1
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```