# VBA downloading file with login isn't working

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, winhttp

I'm trying to download a file from this website, tried a bunch of code i can find and the file is downloaded but shows the html of the login page

Below are 2 versions that I tried. I tried every code snippet I could find on SO and have had no luck so far.

I tried both versions here, they had the same problem but their solution isn't working for me. 
[Vba download file from internet WinHttpReq with login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863408/vba-download-file-from-internet-winhttpreq-with-login-not-working)

It seems like I'm not getting past the login process. I know that the variables (username, password) are wrong in the code below, but I did try every variable I can find in the source (UniqueUser, UniqueLogin, LoginName, every word they had there) and still no luck.

Some versions of the code error on the SET COOKIE line, others give no errors, the file is downloaded but it's still the html of the login page inside the file

```
 Sub DownloadFile2(myURL As String)


Dim CurPath As String

CurPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
Dim strCookie As String, strResponse As String, _
  strUrl As String
  Dim xobj As Object
  Dim WinHttpReq As Object
  Set xobj = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

UN = "hhhhh"
PW = "gggg"

  strUrl = "https://pnds.health.ny.gov/login"
  xobj.Open "POST", strUrl, False
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xobj.Send "username=" & UN & "&password=" & PW & "&login=login"
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText

  strUrl = myURL
  xobj.Open "GET", strUrl, False

  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
  xobj.Send

  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseBody

 If xobj.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write xobj.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile CurPath & "ValidationDataHFIS.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub


Sub ddd()

DownloadFile2 ("https://pnds.health.ny.gov/xxxx/xxxx/8")
End Sub
```

Comment: I can tell you immediately why `DownloadFile2 ("https://pnds.health.ny.gov/ReferenceDownload/Download/8")` doesn't work as expected. You need the link to the actual file, which will always end with the file extension (.xlsx for example). Also, `DownloadFile2` is a __Subroutine__, not a function. So don't wrap the argument (the url) in parenthesis.

Comment: but if i paste that link in the address bar, the file is downloaded.

Comment: You have to process all redirections and cookies in the code which you can see in browser (e. g. Chrome) developer tools network tab.

Comment: what's the real login-password, can you share some kind of demo account? Because the behaviour you describe can be caused by invalid login/password (that would get you back to the login form)

Comment: I can't(((  The login info is definitely correct, first of all, I'm able to login and do whatever I need in there, 2nd of all, if I paste that link in the address bar, I get the login window, I type it in and the file is downloaded. So the login info is definitely not the issue. If you look at the link in my original post, you will see that the guy there has the same problem, he did solve it somehow, but I suck at this, so I can't figure out how. His code doesnt work for me.

Comment: @PavelLint also, this is what one of the commenters said "You have to process all redirections and cookies in the code which you can see in browser (e. g. Chrome) developer tools network tab.", but again, I'm clueless, so I dont know what to do with this

Comment: @lalachka Are you sure that `xobj.Send "username=" & UN & "&password=" & PW & "&login=login"` is correct? The login form on `https://pnds.health.ny.gov/login` doesn't even contain a field called `username`. When I try to login on that page, the POST request contains completely different data (`LoginName`, `Token` etc.).

Comment: @PetrSrníček no, I'm not sure. This is a copy and paste. I'm clueless with it comes to this stuff. But since I posted, I realized that the password and username part isnt set in stone and tried every word I can find on their site (UniqueUser, UniqueLogin, Name, I forget what else they had there) and no luck. I saw the token but wasnt sure what to do with it. Maybe I'm picking the wrong variables? What do you think it should be?

Comment: @lalachka It will be quite difficult to get the POST parameters right. The page encrypts the login information client-side and sends encrypted information in the POST request. Just have a look at the clickhandler attached to the "Sign in" button. It calls [this encryption function](https://pnds.health.ny.gov/Scripts/security?v=vhgI6_JGWAILRW2hX6QASb3G7SVy0g5gRuLisWIp6eE1). I think that the easiest way to go about this would be to use VBA to automate browser actions. I was not able to get that to work in a reasonable amount of time myself though.

Comment: @PetrSrníček you mean by using sendkeys or something? And thank you so much for trying and explaining the issues. I understand what you're saying. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @lalachka I tried [this approach](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/) but I wasn't able to get the page to execute the correct clickhandler when I simulated a click on the sign-in button. I am afraid that I can't provide much more help. BTW, you might want to reconsider and update the tags in this question. It has very little to do with CSV, Chrome or MS Access.

Comment: @PetrSrníček sure. What should the tags be? I wasnt sure how to classify this

Comment: @omegastripes hey, theres a bounty on it. Can you help? I'm lost and the last person that tried said that this probably cannot be done because the site is using some script to send POST data. I'm still hoping there is a way though.

Comment: The site is definitely using scripts, so the only way is to make some reverse engineering job on that scripts, and create your own VBA code doing the same computations.

Comment: You are sending login details to an incorrect login address. Your correct login address is `https://pnds.health.ny.gov/account/login` the page expects `LoginName` and `Token`. The token is generated using `SecurityManager.generate( u, p );` your easiest way is to use a `Browser` object and do automations. or find out if your `IT team` offer you an API

Comment: @krishKM thank you!!! And what do you mean by "automations using the Browser object". I'm clueless when it comes to this stuff, can you please give me some more info on getting the token? I cant ask the IT team, this is for another company, I'm trying to automate a report that uses files from their website. It's undesired to ask them for anything((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending login details to an incorrect login address. Your correct login address is https://pnds.health.ny.gov/account/login the page expects LoginName and Token. The token is generated using SecurityManager.generate( u, p );

*You can still consult with their IT Team to make sure you are not violating their policy.*

Here is a way of doing it using a IE browser object.

```
Private Sub DownloadValidationData()
'Create Internet explorer object
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

IE.Visible = True

Dim URL As String: URL = "https://pnds.health.ny.gov/account/login"

IE.Navigate URL
While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Dim userName As String: userName = "test"
Dim password As String: password = "test"

'Fill the login form
IE.Document.getElementById("UniqueUser").Value = userName
IE.Document.getElementById("UniquePass").Value = password

'Submit the form
IE.Document.querySelector("button.SignIn").Click

'Wait for login to complete
While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
'Verify you are logged in: As we don't know what the site looks like after login in. Only you can do this step.

'Navigate to Download Page. This should prompt to save the file.
IE.Navigate theDownloadUrl '"https://pnds.health.ny.gov/xxxx/xxxx/8"

'Once downloaded just close the browser and exit
'IE.Quit
'Set IE = Nothing


'If you are interested in geting/generating the token using their script you can play around with below lines. These lines come before loging in. Please note: execScript is depreciated now

'Dim Token as string
'IE.Document.parentwindow.execScript ("$('#Token').val(SecurityManager.generate(""" & username & """, """ & password & """ ))")
'Token = IE.Document.getElementById("Token").Value
'Use the token to sign in using your code. That'll be xobj.Send "LoginName =" & userName & "&Token=" & Token
'But not sure if it will work.



End Sub
```

Comment: They know we are trying to find a way to automatically login, I'm not keeping this a secret))) no objections from their side, huge thank you, will try this out today

Comment: i'm logged in!!!! the file isn't downloaded but i'm logged in)))))) trying to play with it. no error, all is well, just isn't downloaded

Comment: so, it's logging me in, that's fine that the file isn't downloaded, as long as i can learn to navigate the site through vba. can you tell me how to call this thing? or where to learn how to do it? 
            <li class="">
                <a href="/referencedownload"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-download"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Reference Downloads</span></a>
            </li>

Comment: this site should help you https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp. On the site, you can find many functions that you can try

Comment: thank you. Are these always tags? I see in your code you're using elementid. How do you know what you're looking at: tag, element, something else?

Comment: everything is an `element`. You can find an element by it's `tag name` or by it's `id`. The site really explains it well with examples and what a `tag name` means. Plese follow the site.

Comment: I did, that's why the question came up. I was wondering what other pages on that site might be useful except the one you linked to, since it only talks about the tags and I have seen code that doesnt use tags. But no problem, I'm sure i will figure it out

Comment: @lalachka on the left side of the site, there is a menus with massive collection of commands. Click other functions that you are interested in and you can read more.

Comment: that's the point lol. I dont know what I should be interested in :) I saw the menu but I'm a total beginner in this stuff, in case it's not obvious. But I think the tag should at least get me started, will go from there. Thank you again. The bounty will award in 20 hours I think

Answer (score 1):

I would make a little recursive function that checks for redirects until there are none left.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

Public Function GetRedirect(ByRef oHttp As Object, ByVal strUrl As String) As String
    With oHttp
        .Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
        .Send
    End With

    If oHttp.Status = 301 Or oHttp.Status = 302 Or oHttp.Status = 303 Then
        GetRedirect= GetRedirect(oHttp, oHttp.GetResponseHeader("Location"))
    Else
        GetRedirect= strUrl
    End If
End Function

Sub DownloadFile2(myURL As String)

    Dim CurrentProject
    Dim CurPath As String

    CurPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
    Dim strCookie As String, strResponse As String, _
    strUrl As String
    Dim xobj As Object
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set xobj = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    Dim UN As String
    UN = "hhhhh"
    Dim PW As String
    PW = "gggg"

    strUrl = "https://pnds.health.ny.gov/login"
    With xobj
        .Open "POST", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send "&username=" & UN & "&password=" & PW & "&login=login"
    End With

    strUrl = GetRedirect(xobj, myURL)

    If xobj.Status = 200 Then
        Dim oStream As Object
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        With oStream
            .Open
            .Type = 1
            .Write xobj.ResponseBody
            .SaveToFile CurPath & "ValidationDataHFIS.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            .Close
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub ddd()

    DownloadFile2 ("https://pnds.health.ny.gov/xxxx/xxxx/8")
End Sub
```

NOTE: This code is untested and would need to be adapted for your use case.

Comment: hey, first of all, thank you! second, got an error 429 here "Set xobj = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest")", changed to "Set xobj = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")", now error "GetResult = GetResult(oHttp, oHttp.GetResponseHeader("Location"))", the 2nd GETRESULT is highlighted, the error is "Sub or Function Not Defined"

Comment: thought that may be GETRESULT should be GETREDIRECT, instead, changed it, now this line errors "strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")" with "the requested header was not found"

Comment: one more thing, when i hover over STRRESPONSETEXT in "strResponse = xobj.ResponseTex", it shows as "". not sure what that means, that the response is blank?

Comment: Correct, I've updated my example to remove those bugs. I'm not sure what the text would be. Do you end up at the download link now?

Comment: no((( i updated it myself earlier and this part errors "strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")" with "the requested header was not found" –

Comment: So remove that line

Comment: the file is downloaded but again, it has the html of the login screen, not the data it's supposed to have

Comment: Maybe that last open is starting it over again. I removed that whole block because at the end of GetRedirect, we should be at the correct page.

Comment: still((( same thing, file downloaded, html of login page

Comment: Sounds like you are failing to login. How do you know that much is even working?

Comment: yes, I'm failing to login, that's what I said all along. It all works when I download it manually though. There are other people with the same problem, I gave a link on my OP where a guy had the same problem. I just don't understand how he fixed it

Comment: You're missing an `&` before the word "username".

Comment: it's not supposed to have it but I tried adding it. Nope

Comment: All my code does is follow redirects. You need to log in first.

Comment: what do you mean, I need to login first. That's what I need help with: logging in.