# VBA WinHTTP request timeout - error connecting

Tags: vba, http, httprequest

I am trying to get information from a site, to do this I've created the following VBA code. However, the request will always timeout. Have I made some sort of fundamental mistake?

Right now I'm mimicking the request that my browser would send, perhaps that is the source of the problem. I have seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294956/winhttp-vba-subsequent-request-cannot-use-the-previous-login-credentials) where this is done and seems to work though.

Code:

```
Sub fill()
    Dim w As New WinHttpRequest

    w.SetTimeouts 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000
    w.Open "POST", "http://www.vti.net.au/calculator"

    w.SetRequestHeader "Host", "www.vti.net.au"
    w.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
    w.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    w.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    w.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    w.SetRequestHeader "Referer", "http://www.vti.net.au/calculator"
    w.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "SESS85bf6b43b33c734cba757f15a25cc79e=7521a51d45d3609955bf90d18f8d0f90; has_js=1; _ga=GA1.3.2146414506.1410196274"
    w.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
    w.Send "Length=330&Connectors=4&Splices=4&Cord=1&submit=Calculate"

    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

Request info:
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am experiencing the same problem, and I really can't find out why it is not working.

Comment: No. I was having some issues where the network was using a proxy, and the program did not account for that. Looking now, it could also be that the session id may have expired. Please let me know if you do solve it.